# Is there a way of clicking on an image to bring you to a page using a hyperlink?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I would like to navigate to a page through an image, and on this new page it will contain the image clicked on. You're probably thinking I am stupid and there is a simple way but I would like to have a range of images that when clicked bring me to the same page but display ONLY the image clicked on.

Bit difficult to explain but hopefully you get what I am saying, I don't want a page for each image. I would like a Page that contains all the images but only displays the one that is clicked on the first "Home" page.

Thanks, the html I have for it ATM is below:

````
         <img alt="Predators" src="Predators.jpg"
         width="180" height="180">
      </a><a href="Page2 - Mercurial Superfly.html">
         <img alt="Mercurial Superfly" src="Mercurial-Superfly.jpg"
         width="180" height="180">
      </a><a href="Page2 - 99g.html">
         <img alt="99g" src="99-gram-boots.jpg"
         width="180" height="180">
      </a><a href="Page2 - LimitedRonaldinho.html">
         <img alt="LimitedEditionTiempo" src="Limited Edition Ronaldinho Tiempo.jpg"
         width="180" height="180">
      </a>```
````

Comment: Your href should point to the image path in your filesystem.

Comment: You sound like you want this: [**Lightbox 2**](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: If you want an actual page: Sounds like you want a page which dynamically shows different content (in this case from a query string passed through the link from the homepage) - so you'd need to write logic for that, either in the frontend using JavaScript or in the backend with whatever backend platform is available to use (PHP, node.js, ASP.NET, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

So the `href` in the `<a>` tag is where it takes you. So if you want every image to take you to the same page use the same page name.(?) If you paste "https://www.google.com" in every `href` attribute every image will take you to Google. So instead of google you want to use your link.
If you want every picture to be displayed on one site depending on what was being clicked on I guess you'll need to use JavaScript. Your other website needs to know which image was clicked on.